# Re-Invocation of setInterval after clearInterval results in multiple intervals (Slideshow)

Tags: javascript, setinterval, slideshow, clearinterval

I'm kind of new to Javascript and i'm having a big difficulty of developing my own slideshow in a proper way.

I've basically set up a slideshow consisting of three images, with a setInterval set on the function of 5 seconds, three buttons to navigate across the pictures and etc.

The only problem I have is, after the user clicks a certain button (which button it may be) the timer doesn't reset.

I've tried a few different ways since I've been researching this since yesterday and I kinf of found a more working way that the clearInterval indeed works after a button click but what happens is it triggers multiple timers.
Let's say if I click twice on a button, with a second apart from each click, the first timer (of 5 seconds) will be reset, however those two clicks create two 5 second timers, making the slideshow go bananas. I feel there should be a .stop() somewhere but I can't figure where or even if that's the problem in specific.

```
function myTimer() {

  var indice_activo = $('.active').index();

  if (indice_activo < $('.intro-slide').length - 1) {

    var proximo_indice = indice_activo + 1;

  } else {
    var proximo_indice = 0;
  }


  mudar_slide(proximo_indice);


  var indice_activo = $('.active').index();

  var botao_anterior = indice_activo - 1

  // var proximo_indice = indice_activo + 1;

  $('.button').removeClass('active-button');

  $('.button').eq(indice_activo).addClass('active-button');


  if (indice_activo > 0) {

    $('.button').eq(botao_anterior).removeClass('active-button');

  } else {

    $('.button').eq(2).removeClass('active-button');
  }
};



  // BUTTON CLICK WITH CLEARINTERVAL AND RE-INVOCATION OF FUNCTION

  $('.button').click(function() {

    clearInterval(intervalo);

    setInterval(myTimer, 5000);


    $('.button').removeClass('active-button');


    var indice_botao_atual = $(this).index();


    $('.intro-slide').removeClass('active').stop().fadeOut();


    $('.intro-slide').eq(indice_botao_atual).addClass('active').stop().fadeIn();

    $(this).addClass('active-button');

  });
```

Comment: Actually the problem is I'm clearing the Interval of "intervalo" which is the var I've defined for the setInterval, but I'm just adding setIntervals while the clearInterval() is still blocking the "intervalo" var which I'm not re-invoking, because in this case I don't know how I can do it.

Comment: `setInterval(myTimer, 5000);`  you can't clear it, if you don't store it.  Did you mean to do -> `intervalo = setInterval(myTimer, 5000);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close the `myTimer` function. That causes all the other code, that's now inside of it, to being called every time the `myTimer` is called by the `setInterval` function.

```
function myTimer() {

  var indice_activo = $('.active').index();

  if (indice_activo < $('.intro-slide').length - 1) {

    var proximo_indice = indice_activo + 1;

  } else {
    var proximo_indice = 0;
  }

} // <--- missing curly brace
```

Comment: I don't know how the curly brace wasn't showing on the code but I've inserted it now, it's not meant to be stopped at that point in the function, it actually stops after the adding/removing classes on the buttons because they're also included in the same function, but it's still not working